# WPF. Работа MessageBox или проблема с потоками

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Имеется приложение WPF, в котором мне нужно открыть порт. В случае, если порт открыть не удается - вывести сообщение об ошибке и после закрытия этого сообщения завершить приложение. Ошибка выводится через MessageBox и ловится try-catch.

По моему опыту, MessageBox блокирует приложение до клика на "ок", однако в данном случае этого не происходит, сообщение выводится, но код продолжает выполняться и, соответственно, крашится при выполнении кода после try-cath. Пробовал выполнять эти строки через диспетчер главному потоку - не помогает. MessageBox, расположенный после try-cath, приостанавливает приложение(но, понятное дело, мне это не подходит)

Код:

```
        try
        {
            port.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка открытия порта. Возможно устройство не подключено.");
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();                
        }
```

UPD: Вариант кода с использованием диспетчера.

```
        try
        {
            port.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (ThreadStart)delegate ()
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка открытия порта. Возможно устройство не подключено.");
                    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
                }
            );

        }
```

UPD: На случай, если каким то образом код выше исполняется не в главном потоке и этот поток не успевает отправить запрос главному - добавил Thread.Sleep(10000); между try-cath и строкой, выполнение которой приводит к крашу. Не помогло.

Comment: Нет ли у вас нескольких потоков?

Comment: Нет, если только приложение не создает его где то неявно(А я слышал, что в WPF присутствует 2 потока - для UI и бэка, но, думаю, их все же явно надо создавать)
Но даже если так - по идее, этой проблемы не должно возникнуть при диспетчеризации этого кода главному потоку, т.к. крашится приложении при выполнении кода MainWindow. Я даже попробовал отправить код  диспетчеру внутри cath, а не весь выше приведенный - все равно не помогает.

UPD: добавил пример с диспетчером в топик.

Comment: Почему вы решили что `Dispacher` содержит диспетчер `GUI`? Вызовите [`Dispacher.CurrentDispacher`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2#%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Comment: Попробовал. Не помогло. Диспетчер получал до try-cath блока.

Comment: Странно, создал приложение, вызвал ваш первый метод, после того как нажал "OK" приложение закрылось. Возможно вы намудрили в месте где вызываете данный метод

Comment: `Диспетчер получал до try-cath блока.` Вы что переопределяете значение поля `Dispacher`? Этого же делать нельзя! А в коде вы обращаетесь через `this.Dispacher`.

Comment: Макет приложения создавал через MVS2017. Код в файле MainWindow.xaml.cs . Сам метод вызываю в первой строчке функции MainWindow() класса MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
До указанного кода присутствует еще настройка инициализации порта, но она должна быть несущественной. App.xaml.cs не менял, там только определение App : Application.
Места для косяков вроде бы нет. Хотя, возможно, нужно было объявить MainWindow как STA? Я этого не делал.

Comment: Я использовал:
m_TabItemManager.m_MainThreadDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

       m_TabItemManager.m_MainThreadDispatcher.BeginInvoke()

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из комментариев, могу сказать одно, если вы хотите синхронно показать сообщение с ошибкой, а потом закрыть приложение, воспользуйтесь методом [`Invoke`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Threading_Dispatcher_Invoke_System_Action_). Он будет выполнен синхронно в том же потоке откуда вы его вызовите.

Код который вы вызываете выполняется асинхронно, игнорируя возвращаемый результат.

Код для теста XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox x:Name="Throw" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Throw?" Margin="10">
        </CheckBox>
        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Check" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Код:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Button.Click += Button_Click;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Throw.IsChecked == null || !Throw.IsChecked.Value) return;
        try
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        catch
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал заменить мое использование диспетчера на ваше. Часть симптомов сняло. Теперь приложение завершается с кодом один, а не крашится при выполнении следующих строк. Но вот MessageBox все равно не ожидает клика. Чтож, полагаю, дальше придется самому копаться глубже. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь)
P.S. думаю, стоит использовать Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(), как тут советовали в комментариях?

Comment: Хотите более точный ответ, приведите весь ваш класс к вопрос. Больше тут ничем пока не помочь.